# Term symbol - how do we know the number of electrons $e^-$?

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, atoms, notation

Lets say I have a term symbol $^4D_{5/2}$. From this I can simply read the **total** quantum numbers numbers $L=2$ and $J=5/2$.

Now the superscripted number $4$ is called **multiplicity** if I am not mistaken which equals:

\begin{align}
\text{multiplicity}&=2S+1 \longleftarrow\substack{\text{if L>S}}\\
\text{multiplicity}&=2L+1 \longleftarrow\substack{\text{if L<S}}\\
\end{align}

But how can I know which one to choose as I don't know the $S$ - if I don't know this one I can't say $L<S$ or $L>S$. I could determine the $S$ if I knew how many electrons contribute to the atomic angular momentum $J$ but I don't know how to.

**EDIT:**

The page from A.Beiser:
[image]

Comment: As far as I know, the multiplicity is always $2S+1$, with the term symbol being noted ${}^{2S+1}[L]_J$.

Comment: I copy/pasted the statement in the book. Now tell me if this book is a garbage?

Answer (score 2):

The superscript in the Russell-Saunders term symbol stands for the *spin multiplicity*, which is given by $2S+1$. It tells us something about the possible values the z-component of spin can take. In your example, we have to solve the equation
$$4=2S+1,$$

which has the solution $S=3/2.$ The possible values of the z-component would be $-3/2$, $-1/2$, $1/2$ and $3/2$ (times $\hbar$). However, it does not tell us the number of electrons in your configuration.

Comment: But in the book *A. Beiser, Concepts of modern physics* it says that multiplicity is $2S+1$ **only** in cases when $L>S$ while in cases when $L<S$ the multiplicity is $2L+1$. This is why we can't just state $4=2S+1$ as it could be $4=2L+1$... so can this even be solved?

Comment: The term symbols are still defined in such a way that spin multiplicity (i.e. the number of different terms arising from different values of spin) is given. A spin multiplicity of 1 for example denotes a singlet, i.e. 1 possible value of spin, while a spin multiplicity of 2 stands for a doublet, i.e. 2 possible values and so on.